# How to disable docker diff

Tags: docker

The following is the disk usage of my machine. I ran `docker system df -v`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND   LOCAL VOLUMES   SIZE      CREATED             STATUS                  
a7ea593ae05e   c265fa50d720        "bash"    0               20.7GB    21 hours ago        Up 21 hours
```

This reports the correct amount of storage used by the container. This container created a 19GB file.
However,
df -h shows the following disk space consumption

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          97G   72G   26G  75% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/aa15e95ad170e94462a8a2064b9f1bad62d3c2ea579f4e7ffcb16e159fbc1cea/merged
```

On checking this folder. I found out that `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9a58de48986643e6284123effe601e57099133ca55e471b548d059906b20434b`
folder was consuming 42 GB.
On checking the disk usage statistics for this folder

```
20G /var/lib/docker/overlay2/9a58de48986643e6284123effe601e57099133ca55e471b548d059906b20434b/diff
23G /var/lib/docker/overlay2/9a58de48986643e6284123effe601e57099133ca55e471b548d059906b20434b/merged
42G /var/lib/docker/overlay2/9a58de48986643e6284123effe601e57099133ca55e471b548d059906b20434b
```

On further checking I could find the 20 GB file in both merged and diff directory.
This explains why it was consuming double the amount of storage.

I never run a `docker diff` on a production instance. So this is causing me more harm than benfit. I wanted to know if there is a possibility to disable docker running diff for some specific folders so that redundant copy of the file the instance creates is not stored?

Please find below the steps to create a minimal reproducible example

Docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt update -y
RUN apt upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-dev
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip jq

RUN mkdir -p /opt/program/

WORKDIR "/opt/program/"
ADD ./ /opt/program/
CMD  ["bash", "-c", "python3 -u program.py"]
```

program.py

```
import logging
import time
import argparse
import random

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # parser.add_argument('--test')
    # args = parser.parse_args()
    l = ['test_' + str(i) for i in range(1000000)]
    with open('/tmp/test_abc123', 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(l))
    while 1:
         
        time.sleep(1)
        logging.info("%s", 'test')
```

I executed the following commands

```
1. sudo docker build -f Dockerfile .
2. sudo docker run -d <image_id>
3. sudo docker container exec -it <container_id> bash
4. Verified a 11 MB file is created in /tmp in the container. 
5. Now, I search for the file in my host machine

satinders:/var/lib/docker/overlay2# ls -l $(find . -iname test_abc123)
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11888889 Jan 11 18:03 ./edf8615137c5b04e14116f6285757d4db170187282a5b51d78f4f77ca4c9b707/diff/tmp/test_abc123
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11888889 Jan 11 18:03 ./edf8615137c5b04e14116f6285757d4db170187282a5b51d78f4f77ca4c9b707/merged/tmp/test_abc123
```

Update

I found this in the documentation for docker diff [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/diff/)

> List the changed files and directories in a container᾿s filesystem since the container was created. Three different types of change are tracked:

```
A   A file or directory was added
D   A file or directory was deleted
C   A file or directory was changed
```

Comment: If you have a very large file in your image, and you modify it in the container, the image will have a (immutable) copy of it, plus each container will have its own copy; this is largely unavoidable in Docker.  Multi-gigabyte files in images become operationally tricky, though, and I've had trouble pushing and pulling images of this size before.  Would it make more sense to keep this file outside of Docker space, in a volume of some sort?  What's in the file?  Can you provide a [mcve] and not just the diagnostic output?

Comment: Does the file exist in your image too; if you `docker run --rm your-image ls -l` is the file there before you start?  (Does the file exist on your host system, and then the `ADD` step copies it into the image?)

Comment: @DavidMaze, No the file is not there before hand. As you can see it is program (program.py) that creates the file. My directory contains only the dockerfile and program.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`merged` is an [overlay filesystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/overlayfs.html), which is a combination of filesystem layers, and takes up no actual disk space itself (similar to the behavior of a bind mount). The `diff` directory is the changes created in that layer, or the containers read write layer (for the merged directory, I believe it's tracked as the upper directory). So either the file was created or modified in that layer, and is stored once in that layer.

If the file is also in the lower layers (e.g. in both the image and container specific layers), then you have likely modified the file, triggering a copy on write. That change can include a permission or ownership change on the file.

To disable the container diff and read-write layer, you can define your container with the [--read-only](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) flag. You will not be able to create files in the container that aren't in some other mount (a volume or tmpfs).

Comment: thank you for the response. I have added a minimal reproducible example. You can try, the file is not part of the docker image(created by the process). Still the file is there in diff directory.

Comment: @satindersingh I believe the file shows up in both. That's expected and my answer above explains why.

Comment: 2x storage for any file that is created from the docker runtime. Isn't this very high? Isn't there a better way to track the file changes for docker diff?

Comment: @satindersingh overlay filesystems take up no actual disk space themselves, it's all in the underlying layers they're based on. You're comparing that layer (diff) to the overlay fs (merged). It's like worrying about double disk usage for a symlink, the bytes aren't doubled on disk, just in your view of the filesystem. Read the overlay link above for more on how it works.